# Access grandparent virtual method

Tags: c++, parent, virtual-functions

Well, I have three classes:

```
template<typename E>
class Iterator {
public:
    virtual ~Iterator() {
    }
    virtual bool hasNext() const = 0;
    virtual const E& next() = 0;
};

template<typename E>
class IteratorPtr {
private:
    Iterator<E>* iterator;
    IteratorPtr(const IteratorPtr<E>&);
    IteratorPtr<E>& operator=(const Iterator<E>&);
public:
    IteratorPtr(Iterator<E>* it)
            : iterator(it) {
    }
    ~IteratorPtr() {
        delete iterator;
    }
    Iterator<E>* operator->() const {
        return iterator;
    }
};    

template<typename E>
class Collection
{

public:
    virtual void add(const E & value) = 0;
    virtual void add(const Collection<E>& collection);
    virtual bool remove(const E& value) = 0;
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual ~Collection()
    {

    }
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual int size() const = 0;
    virtual bool contains(const E& value) const = 0;
    virtual Iterator<E>* iterator() const = 0;

};

void Collection<E>::add(const Collection<E>& collection)
{
for (IteratorPtr<E> i(collection.iterator()); i->hasNext();) {
    this->add(i->next());
}

}
```

Obs: all Set's methods are implemented.

```
template<typename E>
class Set;
template<typename E>
class SortedSet;
template<typename E>
class SetIterator;

template<typename E>
class SetNode {
private:
    friend class Set<E> ;
    friend class SortedSet<E> ;
    friend class SetIterator<E> ;
    SetNode()
            : next(NULL) {
    }
    SetNode(E value)
            : value(value), next(NULL) {
    }
    SetNode(E value, SetNode * next)
            : value(value), next(next) {
    }
    ~SetNode() {
    }
private:
    E value;
    SetNode * next;
};

template<typename E>
class SetIterator: public Iterator<E> {
private:
    friend class Set<E> ;
    SetIterator(SetNode<E> * head)
            : node(head) {
    }
    ~SetIterator() {
    }
    bool hasNext() const {
        return node != NULL;
    }
    const E & next() {
        E& value = node->value;
        node = node->next;
        return value;
    }

private:
    SetNode<E> * node;
};

template<typename E>
class Set: public Collection<E> {

public:
    Set(): numNodes(0), head(NULL) {
    }
    virtual ~Set() {
        clear();
    }
    virtual void add(const E & value);
    virtual bool remove(const E& value);
    virtual void clear();
    virtual bool isEmpty() const;
    virtual int size() const;
    virtual bool contains(const E& value) const;
    virtual Iterator<E>* iterator() const;
private:
    Set(const Set & obj): numNodes(0), head(NULL) {
    }
    virtual bool contains(const E & value, SetNode<E> * & previ) const;
protected:
    int numNodes;
    SetNode<E> * head;

};
template<typename E>
class SortedSet: public Set<E> {

private:
    virtual bool contains(const E& value, SetNode<E> *& prev) const;

public:
    SortedSet(): Set<E>() {
    }
    virtual void add(const E & value);
    virtual ~SortedSet() {
        this->clear();
    }
};
```

Set and SortedSet don't implement add methods, cause they should do exactly what Collection::add(const Collection& c) does.

```
int main() {
Set<int> *s = new Set<int>();
s->add(10);
s->add(30);
s->add(12);
s->remove(10);
if (s->contains(30))
    puts("Tem");
SortedSet<int> *ss = new SortedSet<int>();
ss->add(*s);

return 0; 
}
```

but this code get a error in the line "ss->add(*s);", saying: no matching to ‘SortedSet::add(Set&)’

Why is this happening?

Comment: As far as I can tell this code works http://liveworkspace.org/code/LW251$2

Comment: It compiles fine for me. http://ideone.com/a58gi2

Comment: [I don't get that error](http://ideone.com/S5yQkR). Is that the exact code you're trying to compile? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Compiled for me just fine with g++.

Comment: nops, this is just a simpler version. i will put the real code.

Comment: Code is logically, syntactically correct. code compiles and works fine. This is very basic stuff. I dont think this is compiler problem. If there is any problem then it must be some setting or configuration problem.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I put the real code.

Comment: @BrunoGouveia What about Iterator it is not defined in the code.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: now it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you've posted all the relevant code, the problem is that you've declared another function with the same name in `Set`:

```
virtual void add(const E & value);
```

This hides anything with the same name in the base class; so `Collection::add` is not accessible via a reference to `Set` or any of its subclasses.

To fix it, add a using-declaration to `Set`, to bring `Collection::add` into the scope of `Set`:

```
public:
    using Collection::add;
```

Comment: now, now i got a error message: ‘void Collection<E>::add(const Collection<E>&) [with E = int]’ is inaccessible
Lpoo.cpp:26:12: error: within this context

Comment: @BrunoGouveia: I'm guessing you made the using-declaration private or protected. Try making it public.

Comment: I got, i was puting using Collection::add in wrong place. Thanks dude, you really helped. But i didn't understand what exactly happened, could you explain me better?

Comment: @BrunoGouveia: Sorry, I don't think I can explain it better than I have. A name declared in a derived class hides anything with the same name in a base class; so declaring `Set::add` hides the inherited `Collection::add`, making it unavailable to users of `Set`. The using-declaration unhides it, making any overload of `add` declared in the base class also available in the derived class.